# What function to use in excel

Tags: excel

im working on an Excel spreadsheet that is working as an inventory system.

I have 1 value that i need to look on (barcode) and then i need that value to pull back 6 rows worth of data in different cells.

I have already tried "=VLOOKUP" but its not working for me sinse it only pulls 1 cell.

Am i using the wrong command?
Working with a dutch version of Excel 2010 here.
My VLOOKUP code:

```
    =VERT.ZOEKEN(A2;Blad2!A:G;1;ONWAAR)
```

I would love some help with this.
Greetings,
Michael

Comment: You will need 6 different VLOOKUP formulas, 1 for each cell of data that you are trying to pick up - note there that you are saying "Pick up the '1' column from A:G on that row" which is just column A. So you will want one that picks up A, one that picks up B, C, D, etc. You can't easily combine all of these into a single cell, and honestly your life will be easier if you don't try to.

Comment: Im trying to get for example if i look on barcode 01 Item 00014 and that barcode is in row 40 i need the entire row 40 to come forward in seperate cells

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - couldn't he use something like Index/Match? `=Index(range1&", "&range2&", "&range3&", "&range4,match(matchCell,matchRange))` (entered as an array).  If he's careful in the rows/ranges he chooses in Index/Match, it may work (without knowing more about his data).

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes I agree that's probably the better option I was ignoring for simplicity if s/he already knows how to use VLOOKUP; just a question now of translating to Dutch.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - Looking at his new note, he wants to return an entire row, based on a cell.  Is that possible/suggested to do with a formula, or would something like a filter table, or VB solution be preferable?

Comment: @BruceWayne Honestly I'd say depends on how many columns in a row. Any reasonable data table should be doable with dozens of INDEX/MATCH formulas, but too much data and you'd probably want a VBA solution.

Comment: i have 6 cells that have to come forward after specifying the barcode

Comment: Can you post a sample of your table and how it's laid out? That would help in getting a formula going.

Comment: You could concatinate them together using `&" "&` but I don't know if that is what your are looking for. -- E.g.`=VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;2;ONWAAR)&" "&VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;3;ONWAAR)&" "&VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;4;ONWAAR)&" "&VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;5;ONWAAR)&" "&VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;6;ONWAAR)&" "&VERT.ZOEKEN(A1;A1:G1;7;ONWAAR)` -- It's not the shortest solution maybe, but it will pull them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for data from multiple rows, or multiple columns?  Either way, creating a report of entire rows of data isn't possible with a single VLOOKUP formula. A VLOOKUP formula produces a result for a single cell.

If you're only looking for the data from the columns belonging to a single row, you could create a formula for each of the values you wanted to report by creating the first formula and then copying and pasting that cell in to the remaining cells where you want to reproduce those values.  An additional row with column numbers (1-6) on the sheet where you want to report the values would allow Excel to make the appropriate adjustments to your formula.  The presence or absence of '$'s will prevent or allow Excel to make adjustments to the rows and columns within the formula.

For example if you are creating the formulae in Sheet1, the first row (cells A1:G1) would be:

`Barcode    2   3   4   5   6   7`

Underneath `Barcode` on Sheet1 you would put all of the barcodes you wanted to reference from Sheet2.  The remaining columns would be where you would place your VLOOKUP formulae.

If the table containing the values you are trying to look up are in cells A2:G300 of Sheet2, in cell B2 of Sheet1:

`=VLOOKUP($A:$A,Sheet2!$A$2:$G$300,B$1,FALSE)`

Dragging or copying and pasting the formula from B2 Sheet1 into the remainder of the new table is all that is needed.

The formula above assumes that column A in Sheet1 and column A in Sheet2 have the barcodes.  If column A in Sheet2 does not contain the barcodes, row 1 of Sheet 1 would have the numbers 1 to 7,

`Barcode    1   2   3   4   5   6   7`

and the VLOOKUP formula would change to

`=VLOOKUP($A:$A,Sheet2!$A$2:$G$300,A$1,FALSE)`

but you would end up with two columns containing the barcodes (Column A and one of the numbered columns).  Deleting the numbered column containing barcodes after Sheet1 is filled would leave the rest of the data in tact.

Copying the VLOOKUP formula from B2 to the rest of the new table in Sheet1 assumes that you do not want to change the order of the columns as they originally appeared in Sheet2.  If you do want to change the column order in Sheet1, it is still probably better to do this form of copying and pasting first.  Excel's defaults will make the correct changes to the formula as you extend across columns and down the rows.  Afterwards you can cut (NOT copy) and insert (NOT just paste) the columns within Sheet1 to your preferences, and the formulae will remain intact.

If you are looking for data from multiple rows, you might be looking at creating a database instead. A database would allow you to specify multiple rows and columns of data that correspond with a given value in another field.  This data could be displayed in either a report (a simple summary of the information corresponding to your barcode, for example) or used for additional queries within the database.

Microsoft Access allows for data entry within Access, or importing tables from Excel and other formats.  MySQL is another common database, which is open source and also allows for a variety of data entry.  Unfortunately the learning curve for database creation is a lot slower than learning how to use a spreadsheet program.  The upside is that there is a lot more power from a database in how you can handle the data.